# Access VBA .seek method, get run-time error '438', or Method or data member not found

Tags: ms-access, methods, vba

I'm trying to use the seek method within a VBA code nested loop.  The goal is to use a query to search a table for ID values that match what was identified in the first loop.  I'm returning 'Method or data member not found' The error is occurring on the line 'Set StrSQL2.Index = "ID"'.  Since "ID" is the only column in that table created by the query I tried commenting it out, but it only shifts the error down to the next line 'StrSQL2.Seek "=", !external_nmad_id

```
Public Sub EditFinalOutput2()

'set variables
Dim i As Long
Dim qs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ss As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSQL2 As DAO.QueryDef
Dim IRSfileFormatKey As String
Dim external_nmad_id As String
Dim nmad_address_1 As String
Dim nmad_address_2 As String
Dim nmad_address_3 As String
Dim mytestwrite As String

'open reference set
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qs = db.OpenRecordset("SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest")
'Set ss = db.OpenRecordset("1042s_FinalOutput_7")
'Set StrSQL1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID 
FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;")

With qs.Fields
intCount = qs.RecordCount - 1
For i = 0 To intCount

    If (IsNull(!nmad_address_1) Or (!nmad_address_1 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_1 = !Webir_Country) And IsNull(!nmad_address_2) Or (!nmad_address_2 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_2 = !Webir_Country) And IsNull(!nmad_address_3) Or (!nmad_address_3 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_3 = !Webir_Country)) Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Addresses_ToBeReviewed SELECT SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.* FROM SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest WHERE (((SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.external_nmad_id)='" & qs!external_nmad_id & "'));"

    Else:
        Set StrSQL2 = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;")
        Set ss = db.OpenRecordset("1042s_FinalOutput_7")
        Set StrSQL2.Index = "ID"
        StrSQL2.Seek "=", !external_nmad_id

            If ss.NoMatch Then
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Addresses_NotUsed SELECT SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.* FROM SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest WHERE (((SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.external_nmad_id)='" & qs!external_nmad_id & "'));"

            Else:   Set ss = db.OpenRecordset("1042s_FinalOutput_7")
                    ss.Edit
                    ss.Fields("box13c_Address") = qs.Fields("nmad_address_1") & qs.Fields("nmad_address_2") & qs.Fields("nmad_address_3")
                    ss.Update

            End If
    End If

qs.MoveNext
Next i

End With

'close reference set
qs.Close
Set qs = Nothing
ss.Close
Set ss = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations second of that code module.  Then compile your code by selecting Debug->Compile from the VBE editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about and compile again.  Repeat until no more compile errors.  You would be wise to include `Option Explicit` in every module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a stripped down version of your code which still recreates the problem you're trying to solve.

```vba
Dim StrSQL2 As DAO.QueryDef
Set StrSQL2 = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As ID FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7;")
Set StrSQL2.Index = "ID"
```

When you attempt to run that code, Access will complain *"Object doesn't support this property or method"*.  The reason that happens is because `StrSQL2` is a `DAO.QueryDef` and a `QueryDef` does not have an `Index` property.  See [QueryDef Members (DAO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192855.aspx)

So then you disable that problem line and try this ...

```vba
StrSQL2.Seek "=", 27 'I substituted an arbitrary number for !external_nmad_id just to keep this simple '
```

But Access responds with the same complaint again, which is because a `QueryDef` does not have a `Seek` method.

Both `Index` and `Seek` are object members of a `DAO.Recordset`, so use them with a `Recordset` instead of a `QueryDef`

And if you go that route, designate the name of your controlling index like this ...

```vba
YourRecorsetVariable.Index = "ID"
```

Don't use `Set` there and make sure that *"ID"* is the name of the *index* ... which is not necessarily the name of the *column* which is indexed.

Comment: I'm still having difficulty navigating errors. I've tried a lot of googling and guess/check but I'm confused on how to set up the index so that it states 'code'StrSQL2.Seek "=", 27...'code' the value '27' or 'external_nmad_id' is the only column in the StrSQL2 recordset I've made via the query. Here is what that section looks like as of now... ''StrSQL2.CreateIndex( 'Set StrSQL2.Fields("ID") =' 'StrSQL2.Column(0).Value StrSQL2.Index = "ID" StrSQL2.Seek "ID =",' '!external_nmad_id''

Comment: Sorry, I can't even format my code right in the comments - let alone get it to run

Comment: yes, StrSQL2 is now a recordset.  I'm now returning the Run-time error '3251' operation is not supported for this type of object.

Comment: I agree.  Thanks for your help @Hans, I think it's best to restart this thread:  I've made a new question at this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303535/access-vba-how-can-i-seek-a-value-in-a-recordset-error-code-3251-operation-i)